# Intersection of the kernel of the irreducible characters determinants

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. It is easy to show that $G'\le \bigcap_{\chi\in Irr(G)}Kerdet\chi$. Is there equality ?

This question arises from the remarkable equalities $\bigcap_{\chi\in Irr(G)}Ker\chi=1$ and $\bigcap_{\chi\in Irr(G)}Z(\chi)=Z(G)$

Comment: All  linear characters are the determinant of themselves, so you are just taking the intersection of the kernels of the linear characters (which is indeed the derived subgroup).

Comment: Indeed. Thanks Tobias. $G'=\bigcap_{\chi\ linear}Ker\chi=\bigcap_{\chi\ linear}Kerdet\chi\ge \bigcap_{\chi}Kerdet\chi$.

Comment: However, if you exclude the linear characters, so you only take the determinants of the non-linear ones, then I am not actually sure whether you would still get only $G'$ or if you might be missing some of the linear characters (and which).

Comment: Maybe that counterexample works: in the dihedral group $G=D_4$ of order $8$, the only non-linear irreducible character  is of determinant $1_G$ and so $G'<G= \bigcap_{\chi\ non\ linear}Kerdet\chi$.

Comment: Ahh, good that you found one. I expected one should exist, but I didn't feel like looking for one right now.